# how to freeze countdown at 00:00:00:00 when timer is ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I want to freeze my timer at 00:00:00:00 when the timer ends how to do that?
That would be very appreciated.

Thanx

here is my code,

```
// set the date we're counting down to
var target_date = new Date("Jul 3, 2014").getTime();

// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

// get tag element
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {

    // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

    // do some time calculations
    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

    // format countdown string + set tag value
    countdown.innerHTML = days + "d, " + hours + "h, "
    + minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s";  

}, 1000);
```

**HTML**

```
<span id="countdown"></span>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a simple IF to the end of your function:

```
    // format countdown string + set tag value
    if(days > 0 || hours > 0 || minutes > 0 || seconds > 0)
        countdown.innerHTML = days + "d, " + hours + "h, "
    + minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s"; 

    else
       countdown.innerHTML = 0 + "d, " + 0 + "h, "
    + 0 + "m, " + 0 + "s";
```

Before write your actual time into your div, you must check first, if one or more of values are bigger than 0

So your code will be like:

```
// set the date we're counting down to
var target_date = new Date("Jul 3, 2014").getTime();

// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

// get tag element
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {

    // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

    // do some time calculations
    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

    // format countdown string + set tag value
    if(days > 0 || hours > 0 || minutes > 0 || seconds > 0)
        countdown.innerHTML = days + "d, " + hours + "h, "
    + minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s"; 

    else
       countdown.innerHTML = 0 + "d, " + 0 + "h, "
    + 0 + "m, " + 0 + "s";  

}, 1000);
```

Here is working **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qr9M6/1/)**

Comment: This answer is incomplete and inefficient. @Mr.beginner, why did you accept this one?

Comment: But your answer is also not work completely however I accept this answer but I did not test it.

Comment: My answer actually _does_ work, @Mr.beginner. The problem with this answer is that the interval keeps running while the time left is 0 or less. My answer is both more efficient and shorter.

Answer (score 2):

Since you wouldn't need the interval any more, you can replace:

```
setInterval(function () {
```

With:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
```

Then, after:

```
var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;
```

Insert:

```
if(seconds_left <= 0){
    seconds_left = 0;
    clearInterval(myInterval);
}
```

This clears the interval when the timer reaches `0` seconds, and makes sure the code displays `0`'s, properly.

So, this'll be your code then:

```
var target_date = new Date("Jul 3, 2014").getTime();
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

    if(seconds_left <= 0){
        seconds_left = 0;
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }

    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;
    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;
    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

    countdown.innerHTML = days + "d, " + hours + "h, "
    + minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s";  
}, 1000);
```

Comment: and all other fields ? would be that like this?
like hours,days,minutes

Comment: You construct the amount of days / hours / minutes left, from `seconds_left`. Only when `seconds_left` is `0`, All the other variables will be `0`. So, the only thing you'll need to check is `seconds_left`.